# Fabric error when connecting to multiple hosts with ssh config file & RSA keys

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I have an error when i connect to multiple servers with Fabric using RSA keys and ssh config file.
My client is snow leopard 10.6.8 with python 2.7.2, Fabric 1.4.0, ssh (library) 1.7.13.
I use multiple RSA keys with passphrase (using without passphrase is not a possibility). I added my passphrases to ssh-add. I can ssh to all my servers without problem. I added env.use_ssh_config = True to my fab file to read my ssh config file.

When i connect to one server with RSA keys (with passphrases) all works fine.

But when i connect to 2 or more hosts, i keep getting "Login password" for the second server.

```py
fab -H server1,server2 test
[server1] Executing task 'test'
[server1] run: uname -s
[server1] out: Linux

[server2] Executing task 'test'
[server2] run: uname -s
[server2] Login password:
```

**My fabfile**

```py
from fabric.api import *
import ssh
ssh.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log", 10)

env.use_ssh_config = True

def test():
    run('uname -s')
```

**My ssh config file**

```py
Host server1
HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
Port 6666
User AB1
HashKnownHosts yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
AddressFamily inet    

Host server2
HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
Port 6666
User BC2
HashKnownHosts yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
AddressFamily inet
```

In my ssh config file, I tried removing "HashKnownHosts yes" but that didn't change anything.

**paramiko.log**

```py
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.747] thr=1   ssh.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x1382350L
INF [20120329-17:33:30.769] thr=1   ssh.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_4.3)
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.786] thr=1   ssh.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.786] thr=1   ssh.transport: Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.786] thr=1   ssh.transport: using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.866] thr=1   ssh.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.875] thr=2   ssh.transport: Trying SSH agent key ar8298z4c935cde079ef98763678ecc5
DEB [20120329-17:33:30.935] thr=1   ssh.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20120329-17:33:31.017] thr=1   ssh.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.039] thr=2   ssh.transport: Trying SSH agent key 0273aff478dddddd05378738dhe98798
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.055] thr=1   ssh.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20120329-17:33:31.135] thr=1   ssh.transport: Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.140] thr=2   ssh.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.159] thr=1   ssh.transport: [chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
INF [20120329-17:33:31.159] thr=1   ssh.transport: Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.189] thr=1   ssh.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.218] thr=1   ssh.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.237] thr=1   ssh.transport: [chan 1] EOF received (1)
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.237] thr=1   ssh.transport: [chan 1] EOF sent (1)
DEB [20120329-17:33:31.275] thr=3   ssh.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x10f9050L
INF [20120329-17:33:32.126] thr=3   ssh.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.156] thr=3   ssh.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['blowfish-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:['blowfish-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'aes256-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96'] server mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com', 'zlib'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com', 'zlib'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.156] thr=3   ssh.transport: Ciphers agreed: local=aes256-ctr, remote=aes256-ctr
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.156] thr=3   ssh.transport: using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes256-ctr, remote aes256-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.209] thr=3   ssh.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.243] thr=2   ssh.transport: Trying SSH agent key ar8298z4c935cde079ef98763678ecc5
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.307] thr=3   ssh.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20120329-17:33:32.426] thr=3   ssh.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.444] thr=2   ssh.transport: Trying SSH agent key 0273aff478dddddd05378738dhe98798
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.476] thr=3   ssh.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20120329-17:33:32.570] thr=3   ssh.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.578] thr=2   ssh.transport: Trying SSH agent key 7382deeeee873897883ccc9878972878
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.608] thr=3   ssh.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20120329-17:33:32.702] thr=3   ssh.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.711] thr=2   ssh.transport: Trying SSH agent key 98792098cccccccccccceeeeeeee9878
DEB [20120329-17:33:32.743] thr=3   ssh.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20120329-17:33:32.843] thr=3   ssh.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

SSH agent key 0273aff478dddddd05378738dhe98798 is the same for both servers. It connects on the first server but fails on the second server. I tried with different servers in different orders, but i am always having the same issue with fabric asking for a password for the second server.

How can i fix this?

Thank you

Comment: After checking the server logs, I think i found the problem. Fabric is using the wrong user when it tries to connect on the second server.

Comment: Problem is fixed, i just had to specify the username :)

Answer (score 1):

With the use_ssh_config option set to true, that should pick up the username. You can test it out [by running these lines](http://bpaste.net/show/27769/) in a python repl.